# Add Joomla frontpage to php variable?

Tags: php, joomla

Is there a way to add the joomla frontpage content to a variable? The content is called in the index.php like this:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

I have no idea how to get its content. Any ideas?
BTW I want to do this from the template files.